# How to "loosely" trigger a function?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, closures, selector

I have the following async recursive code:

```
func syncData() {
    dal.getList(...) { [unowned self] list, error in
        if let objects = list {

        if oneTime {
            oneTime = false
            syncOtherStuffNow()
        }

        syncData()  // recurse until all data synced


        } else if let error = error {... }



func syncOtherStuffNow() { }   // with its own recursion
```

My understanding is that the recursion will build the call stack until all the function calls complete, at which point they will all unwind and free up the heap.

I also want to trigger another function (`syncOtherStuffNow`) from within the closure.  But don't want to bind it to the closure with a strong reference waiting for it's return (even though it's async too).

How can I essentially *trigger* the `syncOtherStuffNow()` selector to run, and not affect the current closure with hanging on to its return call?

I thought of using Notifications, but that seems overkill given the two functions are in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Since `dal.getList()` takes a callback I guess it is asynchronous and so the the first `syncData` starts the async call and then returns immediately which lets `syncData()` return.

If `syncOtherStuffNow()` is async it will return immediately and so `dataSync()` will not wait on it finishing its job and so continue with its execution to the end.

You can test whether sth builds a callstack by putting a breakpoint on every recursion and look on the callstack how many calls of the same function are ontop.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is recurse  with `asyncAfter`, which unwinds the call stack.

Comment: Can you kindly provide an example of this?

Comment: @matt does `async` not unwind the callstack or is the compiler too smart or sth?

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. I thought the idea was to recurse without the call stack getting any longer.